# Update the image in binary format asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

if i upload new image only than it stores the image else it store the null
i want to rewrite the same binary image data to database if i not uploaded any image could anyone please help me out

image file stored as varbinary(max) datatype format

my code is

aspx:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/jpg;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Profile")) %>' />

                            <asp:HiddenField ID="imgurl" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Profile") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:HiddenField ID="hdProductPhoto" runat="server" Value='<%#"data:Image/jpg;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Profile")) %>' />  
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="imgUpload" runat="server" /></td>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

my csharp code is:

```
 if (fuPhoto.FileName == "")
       {

           //System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image images = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("userImages");

           //ImageContent = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(images, typeof(byte[]));
         HiddenField hdProductPhoto = (HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hdProductPhoto");
         string imgvalue = hdProductPhoto.Value;


         Response.Write("<script>alert('" + hdProductPhoto.Value + "')</script>");


       }
       else
       {
           int length = fuPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength;
             ImageContent = new byte[length];
           HttpPostedFile img = fuPhoto.PostedFile;
           img.InputStream.Read(ImageContent, 0, length);
   }
```

Comment: "if i upload new image only than it stores the image else it store the null i want to rewrite the same binary image data to database if i not uploaded any image could anyone please help me out" Please can you re-write this using some punctuation? It's not clear where one sentence ends and another one begins - it makes your description much less clear and it's not obvious what your issue is. You could be describing existing or desired behaviour and we can't tell. I appreciate English may not be your first language but please take some time to construct a good question if you want a good answer

Comment: Also please take the time to format your code in a readable way. Your brackets and indentation are all over the place. :-)